# Как рассортировать элементы массива по частоте?

Tags: php

Нужно рассортировать элементы массива по частоте их появления в массиве.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать следующий код:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5);
$frequencies = array_count_values($array);
arsort($frequencies);
$sortedArray = array_keys($frequencies);
print_r($sortedArray);
```

В этом примере используется функция  array_count_values()  для подсчета количества появлений каждого элемента в массиве. Затем мы используем функцию  arsort()  для сортировки массива по убыванию частоты, сохраняя ключи. И, наконец, мы используем функцию  array_keys()  для извлечения ключей отсортированного массива.

В результате на экран будет выведен рассортированный массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 5
)
```

Comment: Немного лишканули...... скорее всего надо было просто, как описано тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1518372/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский познай рекурсию)